# Mysql conditional update with others tables values

Tags: mysql, sql-update, conditional-statements

I have four  database tables A,B C and D ,i would like updating the same column value as shown below. reference  is a foreign key references either refc  or refd  values . Here the tables structure

- A(id_A , price , ...)
- B(id_B , id_A, reference , ...)
- C(refc  , price1 ,..)
- D(refd , price2 ,... )

i would like make that update condition

> A.price  = C.price1
>
> A.price = D.price2

At the moment a one update is done :

```
> update   A  psh
>JOIN B t8
>ON psh.id_A= t8.id_A
>JOIN C t6 
>ON t8.reference = t6.refc   
>SET  psh.price = t6.price1
```

when executing the second query on table D , the first updated values becomes 0

```
    >update   A  psh
    >JOIN B t8
    >ON psh.id_A= t8.id_A
    >JOIN D t6 
    >ON t8.reference = t6.refd   
    >SET  psh.price = t6.price2
```

what goes wrong ? Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use ";"(semicolon) at the end of the first update query
Semicolon at the end will execute your update statement and your item will be updated.